# Is there any equivalent of Perl's XML::TreePP in Python?

Tags: python, xml

Perl's XML::TreePP is really good for XMP parsing/writing. Is there any equivalent class in Python?

Comment: Check http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: Full answer to your question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python

Answer (score 0):

import xml.etree.ElementTree

see http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html